# How to redirect a URL to another URL in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redirect

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web application and I need to redirect a specific link to another link. For example, I want to redirect all requests from `http://example.com` to `http://RedirectLink.com`.

How can I achieve this using C# in my ASP.NET Core MVC application?

I tried to use the following code.

```
public IActionResult RedirectExample()
{
    // Get the requested URL
    string requestedUrl = HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl();

    // Check if the requested URL matches the specific URL
    if (requestedUrl.Equals("https://ExampleLink.com))
    {
        // Redirect to the new URL
        return Redirect("https://RedirectLink.com");
    }

    // If the requested URL doesn't match the specific URL
    // just return a normal view
    return View();
}
```

I was expecting this to be able to see if the `requestedURL` gets hit then it will then perform a redirect to `https://RedirectLink.com`.

Comment: Could you please [edit] question to clarify why you expect `.Path` to contain schema/domain name and *no path whatsoever*?

Comment: Yes, I control example.com and I also control the link I want to redirect it too.

Comment: We're trying to track how many old sites are actually being hit so we're trying to move away from this and use code instead.

Comment: Would this link help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix                                try return new RedirectResult("https://RedirectLink.com");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to redirect all requests from http://example.com to
> http://RedirectLink.com. How can I achieve this using C# in my MVC
> application?

Actually, using numerous way it can be achieved. You either can do in controller level or in middleware or even using [IIS HTTP redirect module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/#how-to-add-an-http-redirect-rule-to-a-web-site-or-application).

How to achieve:

Let's assume, I have a domain called example.com so this domain may contains many path for instance, example.com/home/index or anything. Therefore, I would want either user hit base example.com or example.com/home/index now, you would redirect to RedirectLink.com while either of the URL accessed.

Now, have a look how can we can implement that in action:

```cs
public class RedirectionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public RedirectionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalUrl = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl(); // Check the URL which you want to validate

            if (originalUrl.Contains("http://localhost:5094/AccessTempData/Index"))
            {
                var redirectToAnotherURL = "https://localhost:44361/userlog/ViewCalculateAge";//URL you want to redirect

                context.Response.Redirect(redirectToAnotherURL);
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** You can also check [context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.pathstring.startswithsegments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to validate your condition.

Program.cs:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectionMiddleware>();
```

**Note:** Please beaware of [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order) accordingly.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to implement or redirect using [IIS Redirect module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/#how-to-add-an-http-redirect-rule-to-a-web-site-or-application)  you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/#how-to-add-an-http-redirect-rule-to-a-web-site-or-application)